# Embedding PHP in shortcode $content

Tags: php, shortcode

I have created an enclosing shortcode that is styled to be a button with the intention of putting content in it. I am echoing this shortcode inside a theme file and want the content to   link to a specific relative page. However, I am not using the proper quotations and can't seem to figure this rudimentary php syntax out.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[apply]<a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/quick-quote">Quick Quote</a>[/apply]'); ?>
```

I know this is wrong. Just looking for some guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[apply]<a href='" . site_url() . "/quick-quote'>Quick Quote</a>[/apply]"); ?>
```

Comment: perfect. thanks! am I concatenating because it's already in php?

Comment: @chris_s bingo. You might actually want to use `site_url( '/quick-quote/' );` instead...it's a bit neater